# Pygame Animation Trouble

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

I am trying to animate a wizard walking to the left when holding down the left arrow key and walking to the right when holding down the right arrow key. The problem: I don't know how to assign a variable to the whole class.
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Wizard Game\wizard game", line 18, in <module>
   class player_standing_right(object):
  File "C:\Python27\Wizard Game\wizard game", line 61, in player_standing_right
    screen.blit(player_spr, player_rect)
NameError: name 'player_spr' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = (640, 480)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
gamerunning = True

def load_image(name):
    image = pygame.image.load(name)
    return image

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while gamerunning == True:

    white = (255, 255, 255)
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill(white)
    class player_standing_right(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.player_spr = player_spr
            player_spr = load_image("wizard right 0.bmp")

        x = 0

        player_right = [load_image("wizard right 0.bmp"), load_image("wizard right 1.bmp"), load_image("wizard right 0.bmp")]
        player_left = [load_image("wizard left 0.bmp"), load_image("wizard left 1.bmp"), load_image("wizard left 0.bmp")]

        def key_press(keypressed):
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == keypressed:
                        return True

        def key_release(keyreleased):
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == keyreleased:
                        return True

        if key_press(pygame.K_LEFT):
            player_spr = player_left[x]

        while key_press(pygame.K_LEFT):
            player_rect = player_rect.move(-1, 0)
            x  += 1
            if x == len(player_left):
                x = 0
            player_spr = player_left[x]

        if key_press(pygame.K_RIGHT):
            player_spr = player_right[x]

        while key_press(pygame.K_RIGHT):
            player_rect = player_rect.move(1, 0)
            x += 1
            if x == len(player_right):
                x = 0
            player_spr = player_right[x]

        screen.blit(player_spr, player_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned player_spr when key is left and right, but you didn't assign it on "idle" state. When you're starting game you're not pressing any key, thus sprite is not assigned. You did it before class definition. You can try to put it inside. Also I'm not an expert but I would define class outside the actual main loop.

Answer (score 0):

#TRY USING THIS METHOD

```
class AnimationClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.image_list = []

    def update(self):

        self.frame_count += 1

        for num in range(1,5): # SET THE NUM OF FRAMES
            image = pygame.image.load(f"YOURE IMAGE FILE{num}.png") # loading youre image file
            self.image_list.append(image) # appending youre image file

            window.blit(self.image_list[int(self.frame_count)],(self.x , self.y)) # rendering youre image

            
animation = AnimationClass()

Loop = True
while Loop == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            Loop = False

    animation.update() # CALLING THE UPDATE IN LOOP

    pygame.display.update()
```